# Get last 2 observations of each country

Tags: sas

I have different countries and need last 2 observations of each country

```
India 200
India 300
India 400
US 1000
US 2000
US 3000
US 4000
```

I should get -

```
India 300
India 400
US 3000
US 4000
```

Comment: I know there is a language barrier, but can you clarify a little?

Comment: Are you identifying the 'last two' by the last two records based on order, or by the amount in the second variable?

Answer (score 1):

there may be a shorter way but this will work:

```
data have;
country = "INDIA";
pop = 200;
output;
country = "INDIA";
pop = 500;
output;
country = "INDIA";
pop = 300;
output;
country = "US";
pop = 1200;
output;
country = "US";
pop = 1400;
output;
country = "US";
pop = 900;
output;
country = "US";
pop = 1500;
output;
country = "INDIA";
pop = 700;
output;
run;

proc sort data=have;
by country descending pop;
run;

data have;
set have;
by country;
retain cnt;
if first.country then cnt = 1;
else cnt = cnt + 1;
run;

proc sql noprint;
create table want as
select country,pop from have
where cnt < 3;quit;
```

Answer (score 0):

This assumes your data are grouped by country.  I reckon you would call this a look ahead merge of some sort.

```
data country;
   input country $ x;
   cards;
India 200
India 300
India 400
NZ 4567
US 1000
US 2000
US 3000
US 4000
;;;;
   run;
data last2;
   merge country country(firstobs=3 keep=country rename=(country=z));
   if country ne z;
   run;
proc print;
   run;
```

[image]